# Compare two columns values in subquery

Tags: mysql

I’d like to do the following:

```
WHERE table1.Id IN(
    SELECT Id1, Id2
    FROM table2
    WHERE Id = 1234
)
```

But the problem is that the subquery is a row subquery and generates an error.

Is there any way to convert Id1 and Id2 from columns to rows to be used in the IN comparison?

So far the only way I found of doing it is this, which is not ideal:

```
WHERE
    table1.Id  = (
        SELECT Id1
        FROM table2
        WHERE Id = 1234
    ) OR
    table1.Id  = (
        SELECT Id2
        FROM table2
        WHERE Id = 1234
    )
```

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Roberto: 5.7...

Comment: @Strawberry: I don’t think there’s a need for a complete fiddle when I’m only asking for simple logic.

Comment: @Ricardo For the record, I disagree.

Comment: Please check my answer, it's pretty clear and it has a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know if the best one but I found the following solution:

```
WHERE table1.Id IN(
    SELECT IF(Id1 = table1.Id, Id1, Id2)
    FROM table2
    WHERE Id = 1234
)
```

Unfortunately @lucumt answer doesn’t work because table1.Id is numeric and the CONTACT function creates a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clearer and will allow for better performance:

```
select table1.* 
from table1
    JOIN table2 ON (table1.Id = table2.Id1 or table1.Id = table2.Id2)
where table1.Id = 2
```

check the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d26a/5

Notice it has a `where` clause where you provide the Id you are searching for

Comment: I would remove the fiddle, as the OP has stated that they don't consider it necessary. And note that the ON clause can be reduced to `ON table1.id IN(table2.id1,table2.id2)`

Comment: I actually think that another SO user might find more value in answer including a fiddle :)

Comment: I said I didn’t find necessary to include a fiddle in my question. I’m not against anybody including it in the answer if that would help other SOs as Roberto said.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto but it must be in the WHERE section. I’m compounding the SQL sentence adding bits to the WHERE clause that act as independent filters.

Comment: You are quite right @Strawberry, but I actually find my initial answer clearer (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d26a/7)

Comment: @Ricardo, If you are constrained to only change the WHERE clause I think you should state that in your question. Then your own answer should be the way to go